# How to get latitude and longitude in network location provider in device android java application

Tags: android

I am implementing gps provider getting latitude and longitude from device i am already get the information in device i can implemented network provider that is the problem how can implemented using network provider

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please provide some commas and full stops or rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is basically the same. Obtain a provider (gps, network, etc.), call getLastKnownLocation. Additionally you can request location updates for this provider. But you can't test this using the emulator, you'll need a phone.

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

// additionally (you have to implement LocationListener)
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0.0f, new LocationListener() ...)
```